# Setting the 'actions' formatter Programmatically in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I would like to add a the custom actions formatter programmatically to specific rows only based on the cell content. Any ideas how I can do that?

If you look into the following example, it uses jGrid predefined actions formatter

- http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ActionButtons.htm
- http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter

But this creates the little edit/delete icons on each row.
I would like to write a GUI to manage Properties using jqGrid. In my case there are keys which shouldn't be editable.

The data which I'm getting from the server will look like:

```
var properties = [
        {key:"Key 1", value:"Value 1", editable: false},
        {key:"Key 2", value:"Value 2", editable: false},
        {key:"Key 3", value:"Value 3", editable: true},
        {key:"Key 4", value:"Value 4", editable: false},
        {key:"Key 5", value:"Value 5", editable: false},
        {key:"Key 6", value:"Value 6", editable: false},
        {key:"Key 7", value:"Value 7", editable: false},
        {key:"Key 8", value:"Value 8", editable: true},
        {key:"Key 9", value:"Value 9"}, editable: false},
        {key:"Key 10",value:"Value 10", editable: false},
        {key:"Key 11",value:"Value 11", editable: false},
        {key:"Key 12",value:"Value 12", editable: false}
],
```

So what I would like to do is to show the little pencil icon symbol only when the editable attribute is true in the data coming from the server (Key3 and Key8).
The question here is if there are ways to control the predefined actions formatter to render those icons only on certain conditions.

Comment: Sorry, but you should describe more clear what you want. Do you want use custom formatter or predefined formatter "actions"? What should be different in different rows? Which content of specified column should have other rows of the grid where you want don't use formatter "actions"?